# Echo php code error?

Tags: php, html

My thing is when I echo my php code it doesnt echo the code it echo's numbers in return I am trying to add a PHP code to my website so every week the text on the website would update from a stored file like quotes.txt. Is there something wrong with my php any suggestions? Here is a screenshot of what happens https://gyazo.com/fba5fc414228b1ab2a79bb877642477a

My Code :

```
        <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="teachings">
            <h1 id="teach">Teaching's</h1>
            <hr>
            <?php 
$text = file_get_contents("quotes.txt");  
$text = trim($text); //This removes blank lines so that your 
//explode doesn't get any empty values at the start or the end.     
$array = explode(PHP_EOL, $text);
$lineNumber = date('s');

echo "<p>$lineNumber</p>";
?>
            <h1>Weekly Teachings :</h1>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `$lineNumber = date('s');` and then you echo `echo "<p>$lineNumber</p>";` _what did you expect to happen_

Comment: @RiggsFolly No need to shout here...

Comment: Look at the `file` function, http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php. Won't need the `file_get_contents` or `explode`.

Comment: I guess you need `$lineNumber=date('W'); echo '<p>'.$array[$lineNumber].'</p>';` and `trim` doesn't  remove blank lines, it just remove `space`-characters before and after the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are echoing the currect second value from a `date('s')` function call

I assume you want to echo the number of lines in the array

```
$array = explode(PHP_EOL, $text);
$lineNumber = count($array);

echo "<p>$lineNumber</p>";
```

But if you intended something else, add a comment I I will attempt to change this answer accordingly

RE: Your comment below, then you want to do

```
echo "<p>{$array[0]}</p>";
```

Comment: Hey @RiggsFolly  i dont think i supported what i wanted to do but I was trying to echo the text in quotes.txt every week and the text is already stored in the quotes.txt but i changed the date to s because i wanted to test it. so basically the php code takes the first line in quotes.txt and echo's it on the website for that week and it would keep on going every week.

Comment: See additional suggestion

Comment: But I still have the problem of updating it every second or minute to test if it works. @RiggsFolly

Comment: That was not part of this queston. So ask another question about that subject

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is

```
echo $array[$lineNumber];
```

That will echo the quote whose line number is the week number.